# Appstore connect warning with bundle version

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, notificationservices

i added new targets to enable Rich notifications in iOS. while archiving an application it is showing the below warnings. should i change the new target version number to existing app version target number ? does it impact anything of app functionality or app review?

> App Store Connect Operation Warning WARNING ITMS-90473:
> "CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch. The CFBundleShortVersionString
> value '1.0' of extension
> 'EyeNak.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex' does not match the
> CFBundleShortVersionString value '6.0.2' of its containing iOS
> application 'EyeNak.app'."

> App Store Connect Operation Warning WARNING ITMS-90473:
> "CFBundleVersion Mismatch. The CFBundleVersion value '1' of extension
> 'EyeNak.app/PlugIns/NotificationService.appex' does not match the
> CFBundleVersion value '1.0' of its containing iOS application
> 'EyeNak.app'."

Comment: The version of the extensions needs to match the version of the app; so you need you extensions to be 6.0.2

Comment: it appeared that one can continue, ignoring this warning